# How to show build time with react using vite?

Tags: build, vite

` 
buildTime:{}

`
I have try using `import.meta`,but no time.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with vite config's `define`, aka [Global constant replacements](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define). There's also some [discussions on a Github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3058).

### 1. Configure vite

```js
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  define: {
    __BUILD_DATE__: new Date(),
  },
});
```

### 2. Use the variable in code

```js
const DebugPage = () => {
  return (
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <div class="flex justify-between">App build date: {__BUILD_DATE__}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DebugPage;
```

#### 3. For typescript projects, also add `vite-env.d.ts`:

```js
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

// Global constant replacements https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define
declare const __BUILD_DATE__: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

ok，just do it like this

1. add define in vite.config.ts

```
define: {
    '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify('your version')
  }
```

2. declare **APP_VERSION** in vite-env.d.ts then you can use **APP_VERSION** in global

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

declare var __APP_VERSION__:string;
```